# SQL Server - DATEDIFF rounding error

Tags: sql, datediff

In my sql statement, I need to retrieve rows which `datediff` more than 3 months.

But I found that it seems have rounding problem such as

From Date: 2010-09-09
To Date: 2010-12-01

```
select datediff(month,' 2010-09-09', '2010-12-01')
```

It returns 3 for result.

How to fix it ? thanks.

regards,
Joe

Comment: 3 is the correct result for a datediff of months

Comment: datediff of months ignores the day values.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit: What value were you expecting? and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating number of full months between two dates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
datediff(day,@d1,@d2) >= 90
```

Comment: Technically not quite correct.  It would be better to datediff the months, then compare the day manually.

Comment: horseshoes and hand-grenades :)

Answer (score 1):

Datediff(month, date1, date2) will only compare the difference between the month parts and does not take days into account.

In order to calculate the real number of months between the dates, you will have to do some manual work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql)

looks to be a match to what you are asking but you may have to modify depending on your specific definition of what constitutes a 'month' difference (partial months included?).