# Converting a decimal number to years and months SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to get an age in years and months from a given DOB.  Right now, my code looks like this:

```
COLUMN name FORMAT A25
SELECT sNo, fName||CHR(13)||lName Name, sex, TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE - dob) / 365.24, 1) Age
FROM Staff
WHERE position IN ('Manager', 'Secretary')
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

And it gives me Age outputs in decimal numbers (such as 58.6) which I understand, but I am needing to convert that .6 into a month somehow.

I am thinking that my method of doing this conversion isn't the most efficient, but I have been searching for hours for a solution, but to no avail.  I've seen DATEDIFF, but I keep getting an invalid identifier error when trying to use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT sNo, fName||CHR(13)||lName Name, sex, 
  TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE - dob) / 365.24, 1) Age,
  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, dob) / 12) YEARS,
  MOD(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, dob)), 12) MONTHS
FROM Staff
WHERE position IN ('Manager', 'Secretary')
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3a57/1).

And this should get you the days as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3a57/4

```
SELECT sNo, fName||CHR(13)||lName Name, sex, 
  TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE - dob) / 365.24, 1) Age,
  TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE, dob) / 12) YEARS,
  MOD (TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE, dob)), 12) MONTHS,
  TO_DATE (CURRENT_DATE) - 
      ADD_MONTHS (dob,TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE, dob))) DAYS
FROM Staff
WHERE position IN ('Manager', 'Secretary')
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so, so much.  I have been at it for about 6 hours now and no amount of Googling produced this.

Comment: I actually have another question open if you would care to answer it, too.  :P  I am completely new to SQL, so I am having to teach myself different things.

Comment: @Anon4567 -- np, glad I could help!  And sure, I'll take a look and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sNo, fName||CHR(13)||lName Name, sex, 
 DATEDIFF(year, dob, Current_Date) - 1 + ' years & ' + dbo.FullMonthSeperation(CURRENT_DATE, dob) + ' months.' AS 'Age'
FROM Staff
WHERE position IN ('Manager', 'Secretary')
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

I borrowed the function from [Calculating number of full months between two dates in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql) as you've got to both consider negative and positive values depending on the time of the year... I'm sure there's a better way to do the months also, the year should be optimal.

Hope this works in SQL Plus! Same concept though.