# Calculate month from two dates in sql server

Tags: sql-server

calculate the month difference between two dates

Its working fine with dateDiff(m, datestart , dateend ) but i have the scenario of calculate the month based on day.like if 01/01/2012 to 20/01/2012 must show as the result of 1 month.

and another scenario is 02/01/2012 to 03/02/102 must show the as the result of 2 months.

how can i do that.

Comment: Use as `dateDiff(d, datestart , dateend )/30`

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: I think it will still bring up 0

Comment: @huMptyduMpty if month is less then 1

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: What happen in this case `Select dateDiff(d, '1/30/2012' , '2/1/2012' )/30` OP expect to see 2 as result!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Difference is not 2 months

Comment: in every options i just got 0 as the answer

Comment: this is the scenario  SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2014-02-01 00:00:00.000','2014-04-03 00:00:00.000') AS total in that i must get 3 as a output because the end date is much bigger than start date(that means it has 2 extra days)

Comment: Do you have any examples where just adding 1 to the result of `DATEDIFF(month,...` isn't the right answer?

Comment: k for example start date='2014-02-01 00:00:00.000', and End date is='2014-04-03 00:00:00.000' so while on datediff function returns 2 month as a output.But in original scenario it takes "2 month and 1 day".Like in my thoughts is day is still remains it must add +1 month to the output month.got it?

Comment: It will work:

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN
DATEPART(MONTH,'STARTDATE') = DATEPART (MONTH,'ENDDATE')
THEN
DATEPART(MONTH,'STARTDATE')
ELSE
DATEDIFF(MONTH,'STARTDATE','ENDDATE') 
END
AS 'MONTH-DIFFERENCE' 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Declare @sDate date = '1/15/2014'
Declare @eDate date = '3/10/2014'

Select DATEDIFF(mm,@sDate,@eDate) - Case When datepart(DD,@sDate) > DATEPART(dd,@eDate) Then  1 else 0 end
```

SQL Fiddle [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/848b1/3)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.
`SELECT

    BadgeNo AS [Badge No], 
    JB.GHRSBadgeNo AS [GHRS No],

    (ISNULL(Emp.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Emp.MiddleName,'') + ' '+ ISNULL(Emp.LastName,'')) AS [Name],

    JB.Department AS [Department],

    JB.ServiceCompany AS [Service Company],

    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Emp.BirthDate, 106), ' ', '-') AS [Birth Date]

FROM

    Employee   AS Emp

LEFT JOIN

    jobdata AS JB

ON

    EMP.BadgeNo = JB.BadgeNo

WHERE

    1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BirthDate,DATEADD(month, 1,GETDATE())) / 365.25))
                    -
                (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BirthDate,GETDATE()) / 365.25))`

Answer (score -1):

Use the same function and Add 1 to the result
e.g.

```
(dateDiff(m, datestart , dateend )+1) as Month
```

Comment: this scenario goes wrong for ordianry month calculation