# DATEDIFF with WEEK/MONTH gives different result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to know week difference between two dates. It looks like SQL server do round off and gives the different result for me. But I want to calculate if they crossed 7, 14, 21 days.

**I have stored a week difference in a database as like 1 or 2, etc. So I would like to use DATEDIFF with WEEK without round off.**

Expected Result 0, But returns 1

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-14 09:00:00'); --1
```

Expected Result 1, But returns 2

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-20 09:00:00'); --2
```

Also same problem with MONTH, expected behaviour for below is 0. But gives 1

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2014-07-15 10:15:00', '2014-08-12 09:00:00')  --1
```

**How can I get the correct week/month difference?**

Comment: You could look at this similar question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, `DATEDIFF` "Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate."

In your first case `datepart(week,'2014-07-08 10:15:00')` is 28 and `datepart(week,'2014-07-14 09:00:00')` is 29, so your result should be 1 as indeed it is. Similarly for the other cases.

I suppose you could convert the datetime values to `bigint` and then divide the difference by 7 to get weeks, if that is what you are looking for, like so:

```
select (cast(@end as bigint) - cast(@start as bigint))/7
```

EDIT: `DATEDIFF` always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic.

Thanks to @Serpiton for this info.

Comment: Just a little note found in [another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) page of MSDN you may want to add to the answer: `DATEDIFF` always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic.

Comment: So what is the solution for my question?

Comment: `SELECT cast('2014-07-08 10:15:00' as bigint)- cast('2014-07-14 09:00:00'as bigint)/7` gives `Error converting data type varchar to bigint`

Comment: That's because you are passing a text string to it, not a variable of type `datetime`. I assume your actual columns/variables are of `datetime` type? If not, I would suggest you make them `datetime` type first.

Comment: `Declare @sd smalldatetime='2014-07-08 10:15:00'; Declare @ed smalldatetime='2014-07-14 09:00:00'; SELECT cast(@sd as bigint)- cast(@ed as bigint)/7` gives result as 35850.. Whats this number first? I was expecting 0 :(.. i mean 0 week

Comment: Brackets! You need `SELECT (cast(@sd as bigint)- cast(@ed as bigint))/7` i.e. the result of subtraction inside bracket and then divided by 7

Answer (score 0):

You can try DAY instead of WEEK in the DATEDIFF function, and then divide by 7 to get the complete week

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-20 09:00:00') / 7
```

Comment: But if I am dealing with Month, instead of Week, Do i need to divide by 30/31/28?

Comment: ` SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2014-07-15 10:15:00', '2014-08-12 09:00:00')` also gives 1. How to deal this.

Comment: Question is how do you want this to return, do you want take 30/31/28 days as month, or fromdate and todate spans over one complete month. for example jan 15 to mar 15, should it return 1 because only feb is the complete month in the range, but if we take from the date perspective it is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your question

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-14 09:00:00')/7
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-15 09:00:00')/7
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-20 09:00:00')/7
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, '2014-07-08 10:15:00', '2014-07-22 09:00:00')/7
```

Answer (score 0):

Kiran Hedge's answer cover the weeks, for the months you can use

```
declare @datestart datetime = '2014-07-09 10:15:00'
declare @datestop datetime = '2014-08-08 09:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @datestart, @datestop)
     - CAST(((DATEPART(DAY, @datestart))
      / (DATEPART(DAY, @datestop) + 1)) AS BIT)
```

If the days are the same it'll count as a month, the `CAST` to `BIT` is to reduce every number to 1.

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2014-07-15 10:15:00', '2014-08-15 09:00:00')- (DATEPART(DAY, '2014-07-15 10:15:00')/ DATEPART(DAY, '2014-08-15 09:00:00'))` It is not giving 1 :(