# Search Months Between Two Dates

Tags: sql-server

I am newbie on `SQL Server` and I am trying to figure out it. I need your help in a case.
I have table named `MainTable` in my database. Inside the table I have `3 Columns` named `Id, StartDate, EndDate`.
What I want is: I want to send query a month, It will look if that month is between start date and end date. If yes It should return that line's ID.

For example:

In Line 1: Id: 12, Startdate: 2015-01-01, EndDate: 2015-06-01

In Line 2: Id: 14, Startdate: 2015-05-01, EndDate: 2015-08-01

If I make query 'March'. It should return 12

I can write months between two dates but i can not make query in it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you want the count of months or the name of months, what?

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating number of full months between two dates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql)

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `March` and expect it return `column id = 12`
but you can type 3 and it will return the right rows

```
declare @MonthNum as tinyint

select id from MainTable where @MonthNum between 
datepart(Month,Startdate) and datepart(Month,EndDate)
```

Comment: This code is good for me but there is problem when month of start date is bigger than month of end date. For example: start date: 2014-10-01, end date: 2015-05-01. If I query 3 (March) it doesn't return any result.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
DECLARE @MonthName VARCHAR(10)
SET @MonthName='March' -- Here you need to pass month name
DECLARE @MonthNumber INT
SELECT @MonthNumber= CASE @MonthName
                     WHEN 'January' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'February' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'March' THEN 3
                     WHEN 'April' THEN 4
                     WHEN 'May' THEN 5
                     WHEN 'June' THEN 6
                     WHEN 'July' THEN 7
                     WHEN 'August' THEN 8
                     WHEN 'September' THEN 9
                     WHEN 'October' THEN 10
                     WHEN 'Nonvember' THEN 11
                     WHEN 'December' THEN 12
                     END
SELECT Id FROM MainTable 
WHERE @MonthNumber BETWEEN DATEPART(MONTH,StartDate) AND DATEPART(MONTH,EndDate)
```

You need to pass MonthName query should work.
thanks