# SQL Server - Count difference months between two dates

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to calculate the number of months between two dates?

I have this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01')
```

but this brings me 1 and in fact I want it to be 2, I should sum 1 to the result or there is another function specifically for this?

Let me explain what I need, I have months and years, I don't care about the day because is always 01, so each date is represented with yyyy/mm/01, in my case I identify a value and this values appears on '2015-11-01' and '2015-12-01', this means I have it in two months, now I need to calculate the number of months, so with datediff returns 1 which is not right in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql

Comment: What is the logic behind you wanting it to be 2?   If they were in the same month, would you want the "difference" to be 1?  If they were on the same day?   If so, then yes, always add 1 to the DATEDIFF, and you will get the result you want.

Comment: IF your dates alwyas start from the first day just add a +1 to the result or CEIL the number of days over 31 for a quick hack

Comment: @TabAlleman I *think* it's that there are 2 different months in that date range. So, yes, it should be `DATEDIFF + 1`

Comment: Whey do you expect this to be 2?  You might need to define a bit more exactly what you consider a month to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, This will be my suggestion:

Just add 1 to your `DATEDIFF` output.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01') +1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as below

```
SELECT 12 * (YEAR(Date1) 
              - YEAR(Date2)) 
       + (MONTH(Date1) 
           - MONTH(Date2)) AS months 
FROM table
```

**OR**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01')
```

Comment: That's a MySQL function.