# EXACT MONTH Difference in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the exact month difference. for e.g. 6 Months difference from today,
Consider Today and 6 Months before is 2018-01-14. If you see the dates 6 Months is over and it is 6 Months ,1 day.I want to display it as 7 months . i tried the below query but it returns complete months.

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2018-01-15 10:49:36.237',GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

**One using select**:

```
select 
datediff(month,'2012-April-09','2013-April-08') MonthsInService
,datediff(day,'2012-April-09','2013-April-08')/365 YearsInService
```

**Second using a function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getFullYears] 
(
    @dateX datetime,
    @dateY datetime
)  
RETURNS int
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @y int
    SET @y =DATEDIFF(year,@dateX,@dateY)
    IF (@dateY < DATEADD(year, @y, @dateX)) SET @y = @y -1
    RETURN @y
END

select dbo.getFullYears('2012-April-09','2013-April-09') --1
select dbo.getFullYears('2012-April-09','2013-April-08') --0
```

refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106945/calculating-number-of-full-months-between-two-dates-in-sql) as well for month calculation, it will complete my answer overall.

Comment: Select Statement returns complete months but i want incomplete months. for e.g. datediff will return 6 month 10 days as 6 months and 6 months 29 days also as 6 months.

Comment: this is why I gave you in days as well, look at the above datediff: `
,datediff(day,'2012-April-09','2013-April-08')/365 YearsInService`

Answer (score 0):

You can find year, month and day by this

```
 WITH ex_table AS (
      SELECT '2018-01-15 10:49:36.237' 'monthbefore',
             getdate() 'visitdatetime')
    SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(yy, t.monthbefore, t.visitdatetime) AS varchar(4)) +' year '+
           CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, t.monthbefore, t.visitdatetime), t.monthbefore), t.visitdatetime) AS varchar(2)) +' month '+
           CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, t.monthbefore, t.visitdatetime), t.monthbefore), t.visitdatetime), DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, t.monthbefore, t.visitdatetime), t.monthbefore)), t.visitdatetime) AS varchar(2)) +' day' AS result
      FROM ex_table t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
declare @date as varchar(50)
set @date = '2018-01-15 10:49:36.237'

select DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, GETDATE()) as [Month], DATEDIFF(day, @date, GETDATE())%30 as [Day]
```

**Output**

```
Month   Day
6       2
```